# Testing Website's Python files

Tags: python-2.7

I currently have a live server using AWS EC2 instance, Wampserver, PHP, Apache, MySQL, and Python (as well as HTML/CSS for the basic design and structure of the website).  The website itself is completely functional and I have a testing environment on my local computer to test changes before they go live on the website.  I have been able to test changes to HTML files, by simply double-clicking on the files and the corresponding webpage appears in my browser.  But when it comes to my Python files, double-clicking on them results in my command prompt opening briefly with the python code and then disappearing.  The tutorials I have seen on pyinstaller and py2exe on youtube haven't been exactly helpful. What command or programs do I need to use to see the website output of my local versions of the python files.
A sample of one of my python files:

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<style>"
print "body {background-color: white;}"
print "h1   {color:#007acc; font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'; font-size: 350%; text-align: center}"
print "p1   {color:#007acc; font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'; font-size: 200%; text-align: center}"
print "p2   {color:#007acc; font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'; font-size: 200%; text-align: center}"
print "table {border-collapse: collapse;}table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px; font-size: 14; align: center; text-align: center; padding: 2px;}"
print "body2 {color:Black; margin: center; font-size: 120%; text-align: center}"
print "</style>"
print "<a href='index.html'>"
print "<img src='https://victorfont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/home-150499_1280.png' alt='HOME' align='left' height='38' width='38'></a>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h1> Fruit Store </h1>"
print """<form action="1.1.1.A.FoodDetails.py" method="post">"""
print """<div class = "InputInfo"> Please enter Food: <input type="text" name="Food" id = "Food"  maxlength="9" size="10">"""
print """&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Type:<a href="#" title="Select the Type of product."><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px"/></a>
<select name="Product" id = "Product"required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Banana">Banana</option>
<option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
</select>"""
print """&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="Submit" class= "submitbutton" value="Submit" /> </div> <br> <br>"""
print "</body>"
```

Let me know if I can further explain anything. Thanks